# Reading a text file and creating a maze

Tags: c++, file-io, maze

I am working on a program that will read a file containing information about a maze and use that information to find a path through the maze. The problem I am having is representing the maze in the array.  I am not sure how to turn the X's into integers to represent them as walls in the array. In the one argument constructor I use a for loop to go through the file and put each character into the appropriate array index. The way I have done this clearly does not work and if anybody could give some advice on how properly represent the maze in the array I would appreciate it.

```
   /**@file Maze.h*/

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    const int MAX_ROW = 60;
    const int MAX_COL = 40;
    const int WALL = 0;
    const int CLEAR = 1;
    const int PATH = 2;
    const int VISITED = 3;

    struct Position
    {
        int r;
        int c;
    };
    class Maze
    {
    public:
    Maze();

    /*One argument constructor that takes a filename and reads
     *the contents of a maze file.
     */
    Maze(string filename);
    void displayMaze();
    bool isWall(Position p);
    bool isPath(Position p);
    bool isClear(Position p);
    bool isVisited(Position p);
    void setWall(Position p);
    void setPath(Position p);
    void setClear(Position p);
    void setVisited(Position p);
    Position getEntrance();
    Position getExit();
    private:
        int row;
        int col;
        Position exit;
        Position entrance;
        int maze[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
    };

/**@file Maze.cpp*/

#include "Maze.h"

Maze::Maze()
{}

Maze::Maze(string filename)
{
    ifstream inStream;
    inStream.open(filename.c_str());
    if(inStream.fail())
{
    cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
}
//Get the dimensions of the maze.
inStream >> col >> row; 
//Get the exit to the maze.
inStream >> exit.r >> exit.c;
//Get the entrance to the maze.
inStream >> entrance.r >> entrance.c;
//Read maze from the file.
for(int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{   
    for(int c = 0; c < col; c++)
    {
        inStream >> maze[r][c];
        if(maze[r][c])== 'X')
            maze[r][c] = WALL;
        else
            maze[r][c] = CLEAR;
    }
}
}//end one argument constructor

void Maze::displayMaze()
{
cout << '\t' << '\t' << "Row" << '\t' << "Column" << endl;
cout << "Dimensions:" << '\t' << row << '\t' << col << endl;
cout << "Exit:" << '\t' << '\t' << exit.r << '\t' << exit.c << endl;
cout << "Entrance: " << '\t' << entrance.r << '\t' << entrance.c << endl;

for(int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < col; c++)
    {
        cout << maze[r][c];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}//end displayMaze()

bool Maze::isWall(Position p)
{
return maze[p.r][p.c] == WALL;
}//end isWall()

bool Maze::isPath(Position p)
{
return maze[p.r][p.c] == PATH;
}//end isPath()

bool Maze::isClear(Position p)
{
return maze[p.r][p.c] == CLEAR;
}//end isClear()

bool Maze::isVisited(Position p)
{
return maze[p.r][p.c] == VISITED;
}//end isVisited()

void Maze::setWall(Position p)
{
maze[p.r][p.c] = WALL;
}//end setWall()

void Maze::setPath(Position p)
{
maze[p.r][p.c] = PATH;
}//end setPath()

void Maze::setClear(Position p)
{
maze[p.r][p.c] = CLEAR;
}//end setClear()

void Maze::setVisited(Position p)
{
maze[p.r][p.c] = VISITED;
}//end setVisited()

Position Maze::getEntrance()
{
return entrance;
}//end getEntrance()

Position Maze::getExit()
{
return exit;
}//end getExit()
```

Here is an example of what the file contents will look like. The first set of numbers is the dimensions of the maze in columns and rows. The second set of numbers is row and column  position of the exit and the third set of numbers is the row and column position of the entrance.

```
20 7
0 18
6 12
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x
x     x       xxxx x
x xxxxx xxxxx   xx x
x xxxxx xxxxxxx xx x
x x          xx xx x
x xxxxxxxxxx xx    x
xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
```

Comment: It doesn't work... in what way?

Comment: In the for loop I am attempting to read each piece of the maze into the array. However, the if statement is being skipped and only the else statement is being executed so all spaces are being marked as CLEAR. I am wondering how to read the file so that the X's are represented as 0 (zero) in the array.

Comment: Try changing your array to hold `char`s.

Answer (score 2):

To represent the maze connectivity, you can associate a position in the maze with a list of the neighboring cells to which there exists a path. The list could be an actual list, or a more compact representation such as a bitmap: e.g. 1010 could mean that we can go north and south, but not east and west.

You may also find it helpful to use an array which is larger than the maze (i.e. which includes the border cells around the maze in the array) so that the neighboring cells of a maze cell can be referenced without worrying about the edge conditions.